# Using Microsoft Bob on Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, 16-bit, windows-95

I have a laptop that runs Windows 11, and I am planning to install Microsoft Bob on it. I know that there are compatibility settings for Windows 95, but can I still use Bob even though it is 16-bit?

Comment: Why. On. Earth. ? Could we perhaps say the "best" thing Bob did was give Comic Sans to the world… & oh, how we've loved it ever since :\

Comment: But I really like old operating systems and this is the last one I need!

Comment: It is impossible to run 16-bit software on a 64-bit operating system without running a 32-bit operating system within a VM. Windows 11 is only 64-bit. This question does not seem well researched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only possible on a 32-bit VM of Windows 10, which can still run 16-bit
software.

For an example of how this is done see the video
[Microsoft Bob on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Au1ph3BntRI).

[image]

Comment: I will try this with a Windows XP VM instead of Windows 10 because XP is my favorite system.

Answer (score 1):

> can I still use Bob even though it is 16-bit?

On a Windows 11 Machine?  ... No.  No chance. 16-bit software does not and will never run on a 64-bit machine. Windows 11 is only 64-bit.

So you cannot use Bob on Windows 11.

Comment: Is it possible to run this app on a 32-bit VM though?

Comment: There is no 32-bit version of Windows 11.  32-bit is essentially gone.  I could network to 16-bit DOS from 32-bit XP so it may be possible. But not in Windows 11.

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but running 16-bit software natively on a 64-bit machine is definitely possible - it can be easily proven by installing 32-bit Windows on that machine. I think it's technically possible even in a 64-bit OS, but Microsoft decided to remove the support (probably for the better).

Comment: I know we're talking Win not Mac, but on Mac you can't even run 32-bit apps any more, let alone 16. It's not so much as 'is it possible?' sometimes, it's 'is it blocked?'

Comment: @gronostaj - The author is running Windows 11 which only supports 64-bit.  If the laptop came with Windows 11 they would have to install a 32-bit version of Windows 10 on the machine.  If the machine has more then 4 GB of memory then the device would be hamstrung. Can you run 16-bit software on the machine, sure you can, but you can't run Windows 11 on the machine.  Only course of action on that front would be running a VM would presents it's own issues.

Comment: Run it using dos box.

Comment: @Ramhound You're 100% correct, but it doesn't contradict anything I've written. When I say "that machine" I'm referring to the unspecified 64-bit machine mentioned earlier in that sentence.